# Google Geocoder: save returning value in variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am working with the google API and geocoder and I need to save location information (longitute and latidude) in some variables after geocoding.
In this code I can alert return values, but I do not know how to save that values in variable.

```
  function codeAddress() {
    var address = "Streamwood, IL, USA";  
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var loc=[]; 
        loc[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        display(loc); 
      } else {
        alert("Error: " + status);
      }
    });                                      
  }  
  function display(loc){
     alert(loc[0]);     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want to return the latitude and longitude of your address to a global variable on this example.

First, you're going to want to set a global variable for `loc` outside of your `codeAddress` function. This will give you the namespace you need to reference it later.

```
var loc;
```

Inside of the `codeAddress` function, to distinguish the result and your global variable I changed the `loc` variable to `myLoc` and assigned it as a new empty array.

Finally, to get your coordinates outside of the function, you want to define your global `loc` to be equal to the `myLoc` variable defined by your function.

Take a look:

```
   function codeAddress() {
    var address = "Streamwood, IL, USA";
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {

      var myLoc = new Array();

      if (status === 'OK') { 
        myLoc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        myLoc[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      } 
      loc = myLoc;
    });
  }
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign your codeAddress function to a variable. The returned value is then your `loc` array if your maps request is successful. You can then do whatever you want with them.

```js
function codeAddress() {
    var address = "Streamwood, IL, USA";  
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var loc=[]; 
        loc[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        return loc; 
      } else {
        return ("Error: " + status);
      }
    });                                      
  }

  var myAddress = codeAddress();

  if(myAddress.isArray){
    console.log("latitude", myAddress[0]);
    console.log("longitude", myAddress[1]);
  }
```